# Is it possible to sync an iPad via iPhone without a computer

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, ipod-nano

My wife currently owns an iPod nano and is planning on upgrading her phone to an iPhone 6 when she is eligible to upgrade (currently she has an Android phone.

She rarely, if ever, uses a computer at home anymore as almost everything she needs to do can be done via her phone or tablet.  The only thing she really uses it for anymore is iTunes.

Since she would have access to iTunes via the iPhone once she upgrades, it is possible to sync new music purchases to the nano via the iPhone instead of pulling out a computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no designated option to sync music between an iPod Nano and an iPhone.

Neither the iPod Nano nor the iPod Shuffle have WIFI capabilities, so they can not use iTunes in the Clooud. Id est you have to sync you iPod with iTunes on a computer.